# SQL Syntax Error, i don't know the Correct Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE config SET (name, value) VALUES(:name, :value) WHERE id = 1");
```

Hello, i need your Help, i know her is a syntax error but i dont know what is the syntax error.

Can you Help

Comment: This shouldn't be a great mystery, it's all laid out [in the documentation for `UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Answer (score 1):

Separate assignments for the `set`:

```
UPDATE config
    SET name = :name,
        value = :value 
     WHERE id = 1;
```

The syntax for `UPDATE` has not changed in MySQL and has never (to the best of my knowledge) included a `VALUES` clause.  The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) is pretty clear on the subject.  If you don't think the documentation is clear, you can provide feedback on it.

Comment: `code      $name =  'meta_autor';
   $value = $_POST['meta_autor'];

         $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE config SET name = :name, value = :value WHERE id = 1");

         $statement->bindParam(':name', $name);
   $statement->bindParam(':value', $value);
   
            $statement->execute(); `  I test your method but it don't works, I'm at my wit's end

Comment: @FelixSchürmeyer which error do you get?

Comment: `code Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' in /www/htdocs/w01306c6/entwicklung/login-system/config_form.php:77 Stack trace: #0 /www/htdocs/w01306c6/entwicklung/login-system/config_form.php(77): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /www/htdocs/w01306c6/entwicklung/login-system/config_form.php on line 77 ``` in the line 77 is              $statement->execute();

Comment: So the config table does not have a name column. Please add the config table schema to the op

Comment: @JimL . . . The names of the columns are pulled from your question.  The `update` needs accurate table and column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full code:

```
$id = 1;
$sql = "UPDATE config SET `name`=?, `value`=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt= $dpo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $value, $id]);
```